# ASP.NET Web API : URL call not returning

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API that I need to reach via `https://api.mydomain.com`. I created that API in .NET and published and deployed the contents to my server (self-contained application).

I created a website hosted on IIS on my server and added `api.mydomain.com` on port 443 binding only as it a secure API.

When I try to call the API via my frontend website, I get a 500 error. This work fine locally so I don't know what is going on.

It does a pre-flight check which return 204 and then the next call fails 500 error

Below is the result from Fiddler classic

```
OPTIONS https://api.mydomain.com/api/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: https://dashboard.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://dashboard.mydomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8


POST https://api.mydomain.com/api/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 90
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Origin: https://dashboard.mydomain.com
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://dashboard.mydomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
```

My `appsettings.Production.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "dbConnection": "Server=myserver\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDD;User Id=gg;pwd=gg"
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "test",
    "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
    "Audience": "JWTServicePostmanClient",
    "Subject": "JWTServiceAccessToken"
  },
  "ApiUrl": "http://api.mydomain.com"
}
```

I have tried these database connection strings, but no luck

```
"dbConnection": "Data Source=0.0.0.0,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDD;User Id=gg;Password=gg"
"dbConnection": "Server=myserver\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDD;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

I added Serilog to the application to get more useful errors but nothing showed up in the logs

The website logs looks like this

```
2023-04-01 01:08:09 0.0.0.0 OPTIONS /api/auth - 443 - 0.0.0.0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/111.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://dashboard.mydomain.com/ 204 0 0 14
2023-04-01 01:08:09 0.0.0.0 POST /api/auth - 443 - 0.0.0.0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/111.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 https://dashboard.mydomain.com/ 500 0 0 37
```

I have tried using postman to make a call to the end point but that also has a 500 error even with a bad user name or password.

The SQL logs suggest the there was no login attempt so I am lost as to how to debug this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

So i have added more looging and i can identify the problem but i cant see how its a problem.

I am connecting to a sql express data which these string

```
"dbConnection": "Server=VMname\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

In my seri log i see these errors

```
2023-04-03 18:50:23.460 +00:00 [INF] HTTP OPTIONS /api/auth responded 204 in 0.6836 ms
2023-04-03 18:50:38.139 +00:00 [ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database 'data' on server 'VMName\SQLEXPRESS'.
2023-04-03 18:50:38.141 +00:00 [ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'API.Models.v1.DatabaseContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

but i have chopped and change the string but nothing.
Its the correct name, it accepts remote (i can get to it from local machine using IP)

i have even used this string but no joy.

```
"dbConnection": "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=database;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

I have tried using the server IP address and port 1433 but still nothing.
Can anyone help

Comment: A 500 is an error happening on the server. Probably an exception being thrown. But it's hard to tell what's wrong without knowing what the server does.

Comment: What .net version are you using?

Comment: Hello serge i am using 7.0.202. It a self contained application so i done need to install the web hosting on the VM

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer? What is the error?

Comment: I have added more error from the server now. Its to do with database connection not working

Comment: @TheGrownDev I would like to see the Event Viewer error description. Wht did you post all these Fidler errors if the problem is a db connection?

Comment: @Serge An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:443.  The error status code is contained within the returned data.

Comment: @Serge  
1- An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:443.  The error status code is contained within the returned data.
2- An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i have fixed this issue. Here is how, I was getting a 500 error but didn't know where the problem was to did a lot of diagnosis to determine what it was.

1. I added serilog to get more error log. Which determined that i has a SQl connection issue
2. Changed the connection string to this

```
"dbConnection": "Data Source=0.0.0.0,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDD;User Id=gg;Password=gg;Trusted_Connection=True"
```

3. ***THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!*** Make sure you recycle the app pool to take the change when ever you change the connection string.